# Is it possible to hide the user input from read-host in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, input, hide, powershell-cmdlet

I´m looking for a way to hide the user input from the Read-Host cmdlet.

I know I can do this with -assecurestring, but I´d like to save the input as plain text in my variable.

Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007104/how-can-i-use-powershells-read-host-function-to-accept-a-password-for-an-extern

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to use the `-AsSecureString` switch but you can also retrieve the plaintext value:

```
$securedValue = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securedValue)
$value = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)

# then free up the unmanged memory afterwards (thank to dimizuno)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
```

Comment: You should also free the unmanaged memory afterwards, as stated by the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtobstr#remarks):
`[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)`

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure how to use `-AsSecureString` as macOS with the new `pwsh` (I don't know if marshalling BSTR on *nix is supported, as `PtrToStringAuto()` only returned the first char of the password).

Now there's a much simpler option `-MaskInput`:

```
$ Read-Host "Password" -MaskInput
Password: ****
abcd
```