# Enter password with masking

Tags: powershell

I have a simple example pieced together from some other posts:

```
[CmdletBinding(
    DefaultParameterSetName = 'Secret'
)]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$FileLocation,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $True,
        ParameterSetName = 'Secret'
    )]
    [Security.SecureString]${Type your secret password},
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $True,
        ParameterSetName = 'Plain'
    )]
    [string]$Password
)

if ($Password) {
    $SecretPassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
} else {
    $SecretPassword = ${Type your secret password}
}

Write-Host $SecretPassword
$BSTR = `
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecretPassword)
    $PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
    Write-Host $PlainPassword
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx

[How can I use powershell's read-host function to accept a password for an external service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007104/how-can-i-use-powershells-read-host-function-to-accept-a-password-for-an-extern)

When running the script how can I make it possible for the entered password to be masked?

So instead of this:

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -FileLocation C:\Temp\file.csv  -Password secret
```

This

```
PS C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -FileLocation C:\Temp\file.csv  -Password ******
```

Comment: A password typed as a parameter for a function or script cannot be masked that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, your example isn't going to happen. You are suggesting that you want whatever shell they execute the script from to mask the password, as it is entered as a parameter, before the script even executes. Not happening.

Now, an alternative would be to not accept the password as a parameter, and instead prompt for it every time. In that case you could reduce that entire `If($Password)` statement to just be:

```
$SecretPassword = Read-Host 'Type your secret password' -AsSecureString
```

Answer (score 12):

First capture the password using the below statement:

```
$password = Read-Host "Enter Your Password" -AsSecureString
```

This will mask the characters entered by the user on the screen.

But you can not use this string directly. In order to use this secure string in your script you need to convert this to a binary string:

```
$Newpass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
```

And then use `$Newpass` as the password entered by the user.

Comment: you can prompt for password, receiving password using parameter will not serve your purpose to mask the password.

Answer (score 2):

[AsSecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) parameter does this:

> ### -AsSecureString
>
> Indicates that the cmdlet displays asterisks (*) in place of the characters that the user types as input.

Comment: In the code above where would  -AsSecureString be specfied ?

Comment: @dross Wherever you have `${Type your secret password}`